# Count the specific feature in gridview using linq

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

I want to count the number of "d" in gridview using linq

My dataset is some thing like that :

```
 public DataSet TitForTat()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("myt");
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("iteration", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("prison1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("prison2", typeof (string)));
        prison[] prisons = new prison[2];
        prisons[0] = new prison();
        prisons[1] = new prison();
        //---------------------------
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        prisons[0]._state = "c";
        prisons[1]._state = valueOfState[rd.Next(0, 1)];
        dr["iteration"] = 0;
        dr["prison1"] = "c";
        dr["prison2"] = prisons[1]._state;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        //----------------------
        for (int i = 1; i <= _iteration; i++)
        {
            prisons[0]._state = prisons[1]._state;
            prisons[1]._state = valueOfState[rd.Next(0, 2)];
            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr1["iteration"] =i;

            dr1["prison1"] = prisons[0]._state;
            dr1["prison2"] = prisons[1]._state;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
        }

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        return ds;
    }
```

And in the form i have a grid view "gvData " :

```
gvData.DataSource = obj.TitForTat().Tables[0];
```

my gridview has a column "prison1" that sometimes is "d" and sometimes is "c" .
I need to count these iteration using linq;

Comment: So what have you tried? What exactly are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var prisonGroups = ((DataTable)gvData.DataSource).AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("prison1"));
int countC = prisonGroups
   .Where(g => g.Key == "c")
   .Sum(g => g.Count());
int countD = prisonGroups
   .Where(g => g.Key == "d")
   .Sum(g => g.Count());
```

Here's another approach:

```
DataTable source = (DataTable)gvData.DataSource;
int cPrisoners = source.AsEnumerable()
    .Count(row => row.Field<string>("prison1") == "c");
int dPrisoners = source.AsEnumerable()
    .Count(row => row.Field<string>("prison1") == "d");
```

Comment: @Spad: I have edited my answer to show another approach without `GroupBy`. `GroupBy` has the advantage that you can select other groups easily. If you use `Where` you always have to enumerate all rows to sum the values.

Comment: The second approach is wonderful :what is the meaning of this part :  .Sum(row => row.Field<string>("prison1") == "c" ? 1 : 0);

Comment: @Spad: i have already edited it to provide an even better approach ;) The `Sum` was redundant since it works also with a simple `Count` now. `Count` with a predicate just counts the rows which match this predicate/filter.